# How to create collection containing diffrent classes to choose one at random

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a TD game and I encountered a little problem. I want wave types to be chosen at random. I created various classes, each representing diffrent monster type (ex. fast, tough etc.). Now the question, how do I choose random type? I want to put all the monster types (diffrent classes) into some kind of collection, then take one out at random, and create an object of that type, but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Represent the monster type as an enum an choose one of its values randomly. I will not give code.

Comment: You do not need any of my codes and I do not want any codes as an answer, just a way to do it.

Comment: If you can't just use an enum, put the classes into a sortable collection, generate a random integer in the range [0,size_of_collection[ and get the class at that index. Then create an instance of that class.

Comment: I did not see that you were a beginner, sorry. Please know that asking a question without showing what you tried is a way to obtain a lot of -1.

Comment: I don't care about -1 =) I just want an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 ways :

1) Put all your monster classes in an array : `MonsterType[] types = {Gnome.class, Gob.class}...`, choose an index randomly to get one of thoses classes and instantiate it with `Class.newInstance();`

2) Create an enum representing your monster types then choose one of its value randomly and use a switch case to build the monster depending on the monster type.

The second one seems the cleaner to me.

Answer (score 0):

OK, i would do this by creating class `WaveParameters` with number of monsters per wave, speed, hp, ...

Then just create some instances of this class with different data, add them to `ArrayList<WaveParameters>` for example, and then choose randomnly from that.

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of different ways to do this. Create an enum. Or a List of Classes. Or a List of Strings. Or use a random number generator.

Can you generate a number between 1 and 10? Can you use an if statement to do different stuff based on the value of that number? Can you create the type of a particular wave? Okay, then all you need to do is combine those ideas!

More generally, I'm not sure why the different types of monsters are different classes. It sounds like you should have a single Enemy class that has attributes for its type. But that's a design decision and is up to you.

Comment: I thought it would be a good idea, since some monsters would have "special effects", having one class containing those specials would be a mess.

Comment: I would argue that having a bunch of different classes representing the same kind of information is a bigger mess, but that's up to you.

Comment: @user3801714 you could use composition, i.e. use a parameter to select one or multiple special effects when needed instead of coding them into monster classes.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you've already described a way to do it:

> I want to put all the monster types (diffrent classes) into some kind of collection...

Use a `List<MonsterType>` or similar. Depending on your needs this list would either contain objects with parameters or, if the behavior would be quite different, either an enum as parameter for a factory or a factory class itself.

> ... then take one out at random ...

Generate a random int using `list.get( Random.nextInt(list.size()) )`, i.e. generate a random index into the list and access the element at that index.

> ... and create an object of that type

Again, that depends on your needs. If you use parameter objects pass them to your wave generator, if your list contains enums call a wave factory method and pass the enum, if the list contains factory classes call `newInstance(...)` on that class.

There are more (and more elegant) ways to do it but as already said, that depends on your needs and application architecture.